# Shared users using Socket.io with http polling

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, socket.io, engine.io

I'm trying to use Aws Lambda to my application using Socket.io with Node.js.

Because of websocket limitations on lambda, I decided to use http polling, but when the client do the first request receiving the SID, in a second request, the server throws `Session id unknown`, because another instance was triggered and dont have this user in memory.

I tried to use `socket.io-redis` as redis adapter for socket.io, I tried to share the session on redis using the `express-session` and `express-socket.io-session` but nothing works.

On my server.js I have:

```
io.adapter(
  redisAdapter({
    host: REDIS_URL,
    port: REDIS_PORT,
    requestsTimeout: 5000
  })
);

var redisStoreInstance = new RedisStore({
  host: REDIS_URL,
  port: REDIS_PORT,
  client: redis
});

var sessionMiddleware = session({
  store: redisStoreInstance,
  secret: "secret",
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
});

io.use(sharedsession(sessionMiddleware, {
  autoSave:true
}));

io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.handshake.session.save();
});
```

Analysing the engine.io (lib used by socket.io) code, I saw where the exception is throw:

```
if (!this.clients.hasOwnProperty(sid)) {
    debug('unknown sid "%s"', sid);
    return fn(Server.errors.UNKNOWN_SID, false);
}
```

And this variable `clients` dont have a complex implementation, is only a local variable.

So, my question is:

**Is possible to create a shared user store with socket.io for multiple instances?**
(Save on redis for example and make socket.io find the session id for this redis instance instead of memory variable).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related discussion: [Is it possible to use socket.io with AWS lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33926619/is-it-possible-to-use-socket-io-with-aws-lambda).

Comment: As best I can tell from various reading, AWS Lambda is fundamentally an architectural mismatch for long lived socket.io connections.

Comment: As best I can tell from various reading, AWS Lambda is fundamentally an architectural mismatch for long lived socket.io connections.